# Google Cloud Messaging - Using "delay_while_idle" - App Server C#

Tags: c#, android, winforms, google-cloud-messaging

First of all, I'm feeling bad asking this question because I think that the error it's something simple.

I'm using GCM on android and I wrote an app server in C#. Everything works fine but I have a doubt trying to specify delay_while_idle parameter. I put it in true but I doesn't work, I mean, if I have the device locked, the gcm messaging arrives immediately.

Here is my code

```
   private string SendNotification( )
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        String GCM_URL = @"https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

        string collapseKey = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();



        data.Add("data.title", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("title"));
        data.Add("data.description", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("description"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendFormat("registration_id={0}&collapse_key={1}", REGISTRATION_ID, collapseKey);
        sb.AppendFormat("&delay_while_idle=true");


        foreach (string item in data.Keys)
        {
            if (item.Contains("data."))
                sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", item, data[item]);
        }

        string msg = sb.ToString();

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GCM_URL);
        req.Method         = "POST";
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=" + API_KEY);
        req.ContentType    = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;;charset=UTF-8";
        req.ContentLength  = msg.Length;

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter oWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            oWriter.Write(msg);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string respData = sr.ReadToEnd();

                if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)   // OK = 200
                {
                    if (respData.StartsWith("id="))
                    {
                        result = "ok";
                    }
                    else
                        result = respData.ToString();
                }
                else if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError || resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadGateway )    // 500
                    result = "Internal server error";
                else if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable || resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadGateway )    // 503
                    result = "Server unavailable";
                else if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)          // 401
                    result = "invalid api key";
                else
                    result = "Error: " + resp.StatusCode;
            }
        }

        return result;


    }
```

It's correct the way that I'm using the parameter "delay_while_idle"? (I tried with "delay_while_idle=1" but was the same)

Probably, I'm using a wrong format

[UPDATE]
Reading the GCM Documentation, I saw that I must put it in JSON format

Answer (score 1):

The default value for delay_while_idle have to be false, and it must be a JSON boolean.